# Trying to open up Chrome Web driver, it opens and closes

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

So when I open try to run it like this it works, but when i try to run it in my class it opens and closes

````
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://instagram.com")

##But when I try it In my class it opens and closes,

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep



class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("http://google.com")


InstaBot()```
````

Comment: it works fine for me. It doesn't close.

Comment: I used `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())` ; `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had not created a Instance of Class. Try this one.

```
from selenium import webdriver

class MyClass():

def __init__(self):
    self.driverpath = "C:/browserdrivers/chromedriver.exe"

def open_browser(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.driverpath)

def open_site(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)

c = MyClass()
c.open_browser()
c.open_site('https://instagram.com')
```